# How to get rid of youndoo?

Tags: malware, web-browser, virus, antimalware, virus-removal

Lately my computer was infected with an adware called youndoo , this opens a search page every time I open a browser , tried resetting the browsers and used a malware remover , but didn't work , how can I remove this?